# A question about a property of Gauss sum.

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I am reading [the book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004YW6GIK) and I have some questions about Gauss sum. The Gauss sum is defined in the end of page 4, formula (1.14), by
\begin{align}
g(m,c)=\sum_{a \mod c} \left( \frac{a}{c} \right)_n \psi(\frac{am}{c}),
\end{align}
where $m,c \in \mathfrak{o}_S$, $c \neq 0$, $\left( \frac{a}{c} \right)_n$ is the n-th power residue symbol, and 
\begin{align}
\mathfrak{o}_S = \{x \in F: |x|_v \leq 1 \text{ for } v \not\in S\},
\end{align}
$S$ is a fnite set of places of $F$ containing all the archimedean places, $F$ is an algebraic number field containing all the group of $2n$-th roots of unity.

Let $F_S = \prod_{v \in S} F_v$ and $\psi$ a character of $F$.

On page 5, the formula (1.15), let $h(a) = g(p^a, p^a)$. It is said that $h(a)$ is nonzero only if $n|a$, in which case $h(a) = (q-1)q^{a-1}$. I tried to prove this but not successful. We have
$$
h(a)=g(p^a, p^{a}) = \sum_{a \mod p^a} \left( \frac{a}{p^a} \right)_n \psi(a) \\
= \sum_{a \mod p^a} \left( \frac{a}{p} \right)_n \cdots \left( \frac{a}{p} \right)_n \psi(a).
$$
But I don't know how to continue. Thank you very much.